# Error occoured while using file_picker plugin

Tags: android, flutter, androidx, filepicker

I am getting an error after using the file picker package.
I searched about this a lot and still can't able to solve the problem.
I tried flutter clean also but it also doesn't work.

The error is below:
{

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> F:\flutter\bit_sms\build\pfile_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin contacts_service...
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:8: error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
^
C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\embedding\engine\plugins\lifecycle\FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
^
symbol:   class Lifecycle
location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
}

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions they are:

1. Open Android Studio and click on refactor -> Migrate to androidX
2. Add implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0' in android\app\build.gradle inside dependencies